# "Sort the volts and the amps will sort themselves"

Tags: voltage, current

I once heard this quote:

> Sort the volts and the amps will sort themselves.

Obviously there is much more to electricity than this, and you cannot just ignore current, but is there any element of truth in this quote?

Comment: ideal resistor maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

What it is trying to convey is that if you have a known circuit and know the voltage between any two points then the current between the points can be calculated - it is not essential to measure it in order for it to be known. Current and Voltage are interdependant.

In a simple circuit where a resistor has a voltage across it and a current in it, it can be considered that

- A current flows through the resistor and as a result a voltage appears across the resistor.

or

- A voltage is applied across the resistor and as a result a current flows.

or

- An increasing Voltage is applied until a desired current is reached, with the required voltage being set by the circuit resistance

or

- An increasing current is created in a resistor until a desired voltage is reached*, with the required current being set by the circuit resistance

All these situations are equivalent.

Ohm's law (usually, more or less, ... :-) ) applies.
This can be written by rearranging, as any of

V = I x R
R = V/ I
I = V / R

where V = voltage, I = current, R = resistance.

---

*The example where "an increasing current is applied" sounds artificial to most people as we are used to dealing with voltage sources (batteries, mains , ...). A variable current source allows this to be implemented. A solar panel is close to a variable current source in normal operation with current being controlled by insolation (light) level.